# Why there is no a vector quantity in $P=\sqrt{2mK.E}$

Tags: momentum, vectors

Personally, If I saw this law I would say that momentum is a scalar quantity, because I know that (scalar quantity X scalar quantity = scalar quantity).

Since momentum is a vector quantity, So why there is no any vector quantity in this law to make momentum as an vector quantity (vector quantity X scalar quantity = vector quantity)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not the momentum vector, it is the modulus.

If you recall the definition of kinetic energy,

$$K=\frac{1}{2} m v^2 = \frac{1}{2} \frac{m^2}{m}v^2 = \frac{1}{2 m} (mv)^2=\frac{p^2}{2m}$$

So $K=p^2/2m$, that is

$$ p^2= 2mK$$

Notice that this is a scalar because it is a squared quantity. $\vec{p}\cdot\vec{p}=p^2$

Consequently you can get

$p=\sqrt{2mK}$

But this is the modulus, that is

$$|\vec{p}|=\sqrt{2mK}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\vec p = m\,\vec v \Rightarrow \vec p \cdot  \vec p = m^2\,\vec v\cdot \vec v \Rightarrow p^2 = m^2 v^2$ where $p$ and $v$ are the magnitudes of the vector quantities.

Which produce the relationship $p = \sqrt{2mE_{\rm k}}$ where $E_{\rm k} =\frac 12 m v^2$